# Ignoring filler words in part of speech pattern NLTK

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I have rule based text matching program that I've written that operates based on rules created using specific POS patterns. So for example one rule is:

```
pattern = [('PRP', "i'll"), ('VB', ('jump', 'play', 'bite', 'destroy'))]
```

In this case when analyzing my input text this will only return results in a string that fit grammatically to this specific pattern so:

```
I'll jump
I'll play
I'll bite
I'll destroy
```

My question involves extracting the same meaning of the text when people use the same text but add a superlative or any type of word that doesn't change context, right now it only does **exact** matches, but wont catch phrases like the first string in this example:

```
I'll 'freaking' jump 
'Dammit' I'll play
I'll play 'dammit'
```

The word doesn't have have to be specific its just making sure the program can still identify the same pattern with the addition of a non-contextual superlative or any other type of word with the same purpose. This is the flagger I've written and I've given an example string:

```
string_list = [('Its', 'PRP$'), ('annoying', 'NN'), ('when', 'WRB'), ('a', 'DT'), ('kid', 'NN'), ('keeps', 'VBZ'), ('asking', 'VBG'), ('you', 'PRP'), ('to', 'TO'), ('play', 'VB'), ('but', 'CC'), ("I'll", 'NNP'), ('bloody', 'VBP'), ('play', 'VBP'), ('so', 'RB'), ('it', 'PRP'), ('doesnt', 'VBZ'), ('cry', 'NN')]

def find_match_pattern(string_list, pattern_dict):

    from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

    analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer() # does a sentiment analysis on the output string

    filt_ = ['Filter phrases'] # not the patterns just phrases I know I dont want

    filt_tup = [x.lower() for x in filt_]

    for rule, pattern in pattern_dict.items(): # pattern dict is an Ordered Diction courtesy of collections

        num_matched = 0

        for idx, tuple in enumerate(string_list): # string_list is the input string that has been POS tagged
            matched = False

            if tuple[1] == list(pattern.keys())[num_matched]:

                if tuple[0] in pattern[tuple[1]]:
                    num_matched += 1
                else:
                    num_matched = 0
            else:
                num_matched = 0

            if num_matched == len(pattern): # if the number of matching words equals the length of the pattern do this

                matched_string = ' '.join([i[0] for i in string_list]) # Joined for the sentiment analysis score
                vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(matched_string)
                sentiment = vs['compound']

                if matched_string in filt_tup:
                    break

                elif (matched_string not in filt_tup) or (sentiment < -0.8):
                    matched = True
                    print(matched, '\n', matched_string, '\n', sentiment)

                return (matched, sentiment, matched_string, rule)
```

I know its a really abstract (or down the rabbit hole) question, so it may be a discussion but if anyone has experience with this it would be awesome to see what you recommend.

Comment: Do you need to use NLTK or this is just an example?

Comment: @TiagoDuque I use NLTK's POS tagger, but I know spacy has one that works rather fluidly, as long as its within is own frame work which makes it less modular. But I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: I'm trying to build you an example in spacy. If it works, I'll post it.

Comment: Just found out that spacy ner treats freaking as a verb, Dammit as proper noun lol.

Comment: @TiagoDuque the word itself doesn't matter too much, mainly the type but I'm familiar with the difference in Spacy's and NLTK's pos tags which can be a bit frustrating at times.

Comment: I see. I'll try to use some more "common" adverbs and present you a matcher which works with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be answered using Spacy's dependecy tagger. Spacy provides a matcher with many optional and switchable options.

In the case below, instead of basing on specific words or Parts of Speech, the focus was looking at certain sintatic functions, such as the nominal subject and the auxiliary verbs.

Here's a quick example:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load('en')
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab, validate=True)
pattern = [{'DEP': 'nsubj', 'OP': '+'}, # OP + means it has to be at least one nominal subject - usually a pronoun
           {'DEP': 'aux', 'OP': '?'}, # OP ? means it can have one or zero auxiliary verbs
           {'POS': 'ADV', 'OP': '?'}, # Now it looks for an adverb. Also, it is not needed (OP?)
           {'POS': 'VERB'}] # Finally, I've generallized it with a verb, but you can make one pattern for each verb or write a loop to do it.
matcher.add("NVAV", None, pattern)
phrases = ["I\'ll really jump.",
           "Okay, I\'ll play.",
           "Dammit I\'ll play",
           "I\'ll play dammit",
          "He constantly plays it",
          "She usually works there"]

for phrase in phrases:
    doc = nlp(phrase)

    matches = matcher(doc)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        span = doc[start:end]
        print('Matched:',span.text)
```

> Matched: I'll really jump
>
> Matched: I'll play
>
> Matched: I'll play
>
> Matched: I'll play
>
> Matched: He constantly plays
>
> Matched: She usually works

You can always test your patterns in the live example: [Spacy Live Example](https://explosion.ai/demos/matcher?text=%22I%27ll%20really%20jump.%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Okay%2C%20I%27ll%20play.%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Dammit%20I%27ll%20play%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22I%27ll%20play%20dammit%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22He%20constantly%20plays%20it%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22She%20usually%20works%20there%22&model=en_core_web_sm&pattern=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22DEP%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22nsubj%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22OP%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%2B%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22POS%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22VERB%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22OP%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%3F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A2%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22POS%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22ADV%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22OP%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%3F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A4%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22POS%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22VERB%22%7D%5D%7D%5D)

You can extend it as you will. Read more here:https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching

Comment: This is awesome, I'm going to extend it a lot more since I have 16 other rules to define but I'm going to mark this answered tentatively.

Comment: so I've expanded the pattern rules the only issue is none of them are printing. I figured that maybe I wasn't being specific enough, however when running your example it also didn't print any of the example phrases as well. They all work in the visualizer, and the code is executing fine but no prints on things that should be printed.

Comment: What model files are you using? en.sm?

Comment: Correct `en.sm`

Comment: The key is in the pattern arguments. I also had some problems while prepping the example. There are several different options and, as you said, the tags are different. Some of them are case sensitive including, check that.